# Leaflet.js circleMarker transition

Tags: leaflet

Does anyone know how I can do transitions in leaflet.js with a circleMarker please?
In older versions (0.7 if I am not mistaken) the following css used to do the trick

```
.leaflet-clickable {
        transition: all .3s;
    }
```

but not anymore. I am using `version 1.3.1`

Comment: have you checked the class of the circleMarker, most likely it has changed

Answer (score 3):

Set a [custom class on your marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#path-classname) and use it to set your transition. For example:

Using this marker

```
L.circleMarker([0, 0], {
    className: 'circle-transition'
}).addTo(map)
```

You can have a transition on hover with

```css
.circle-transition:hover {
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s
}
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 4);

L.circleMarker([0, 0], {
    radius: 100, 
    className: 'circle-transition',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map)
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


@keyframes fadeIn { 
  from { fill-opacity:0; } 
  to { fill-opacity:0.5; } 
}
.circle-transition {
   animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 fadeIn;
}
.circle-transition:hover {
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.4/leaflet.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.4/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! thats a good one! Do you know if there is way to have transitions when the circleMarker is drawn/created on the map please?

Comment: You could try `@keyframes` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes I've modified my example to show how it could be done.